# How to get the property value of an object using index in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, object

I am creating multiple HTML elements.
Elements have different properties.

I would like to get the property name, and the its value using index.

```
var elements = [
            {"type":"div","className":"items","id":"item-0-"+item}
            {"type":"div","className":"items","id":"item-0-"+item}
            {"type":"input","type":"number","step":1,"min":1}
        ];
```

I want to access it like,

```
        alert(elements[0][1]); //"className":"items"
        alert(elements[0][1].value); //items
```

I tried that but It is not working.

Comment: [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795/1529630) No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should allow you to see everything:

```
var i, j, k;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     for (j in elements[i]) {
         alert(i+' '+j+' is '+elements[i][j]);
         console.log(i+' '+j+' is '+elements[i][j]); // This is less annoying than alerts
     }
}
```

Comment: how to output the property name? //className

Comment: My problem is, I am going to add it in a loop, and there are different property names. Can I get the value using index?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var name = Object.keys(elements[0])[1]; // Item name = 'classname'
alert(elements[0][name]); // Item value = 'items'
```